# how to run two foreach loop in one loop in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I don't know how to describe my problem but what result I wanted is [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGd02.jpg)

My Code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * From Deals_FF Where Deal_Code = '" + Deal_Code + "'", con))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int n = SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows.Add();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["Deal_Name"].ToString();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = 1;
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "FF";
                    break;
                }

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int n1 = SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows.Add();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n1].Cells[1].Value = dr["Item_Name"].ToString();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n1].Cells[2].Value = 0;
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n1].Cells[3].Value = dr["Quantity"].ToString();
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n1].Cells[4].Value = 0;
                    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n1].Cells[5].Value = "FF";
                }
            }
        }
```

Any Better way to solve this problem?
I add two foreach loop to solve my problem but the code I do is not good how can I do it in better way please guide?

Comment: What's the difference between two loop?

Comment: @D-Shih Actually I have deals table and every deal has multiple items like Deal 1 has `Pizza`,`Fries`,`Drink` I just want to select deal name first and then it's items with price 0 I don't want to repeat the price with every item that's why in the first loop I break it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a `bool` to control your loop then combine two `foreach`. when you had run first time `bool` set false.

```
bool IsFirst = true;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    int n = SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows.Add();
    if (IsFirst)
    {
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["Deal_Name"].ToString();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = 1;
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "FF";
        IsFirst = false;
    } else
    {
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["Item_Name"].ToString();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = 0;
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = dr["Quantity"].ToString();
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = 0;
        SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "FF";
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Or you don't need the first loop only assign values like this.

```
int n = SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows.Add();
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["Deal_Name"].ToString();
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = 1;
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = dr["Deal_Price"].ToString();
SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "FF";

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    n = SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows.Add();
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.ClearSelection();
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["Item_Name"].ToString();
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = 0;
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = dr["Quantity"].ToString();
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = 0;
    SalesRegisterControl.Instance.Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "FF";
}
```

Comment: Better to put the whole `IsFirst` outside the loop and assign values from the first row. Inside the loop is a hack.